# page not found in zend server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using ZendServer-CE-php-5.3.14-5.6.0-SP4-Windows_x86(zend server+zend framework1) on my win7 machine.

1. I used ZendStudio.exe to create a project zf-tutorial1,
2. use below zf commands to create 3 actions:

   ```
   zf create action add Index
   zf create action edit Index
   zf create action delete Index
   ```
3. I checked `D:\program files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf`

a. `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` (it is enabled by default)

b. changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`, there are 3 places.

Then, I open below urls:

`http://localhost/zf-tutorial1/public/`  ... works well, shows "welcome to the zend framework..."

`http://localhost/zf-tutorial1/public/add` ...  shows "An error occurred  Page not found"

So what is the problem? so strange, yesterday it works well, but today when I turn on my computer, it shows "page not found", so strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason: I put the wrong url, right one is: `http://localhost/zf-tutorial/public/index/add`